# unresolvable problem during distribution upgrade. How to find more details

Tags: upgrade, lts, do-release-upgrade

I do-release-upgrade.
It updated package list.
Calculated changes.
Then stopped, saying:

### cannot compute system update. Discovered unresolvable problem. Then, aborted upgrading and returned everything to the original state.

It didn't give any details about the problemmatic packages, it stumbled upon during upgrade. Is there a way to find out. Maybe, there is some log, that I can look at, or some other soluution, where I can find out more detail?

Answer (score 0):

have a look in /var/log

**dpkg.log**  - this is the log of the package installer

**unattended-upgrades/** - this folder has more logs that might help

Comment: The unattended-upgrades log files are upgrades made by the unattended-upgrades script and those are regular package updates, not release upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

The release upgrader writes log files to /var/log/dist-upgrade.  You should first look at /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and if there was a failure to calculate the upgrade then look at /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log.